# PDF file placed in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-acrobat

I am placing a PDF into an illustrator file and where there should be white in the PDF it is transparent. How can I fix this? I want the PDF to have white where there should be white. When I put a drop shadow on the PDF image it is transparent and where the white should be it has a shadow. I've tried looking at the settings and everything. Please help.

Comment: please provide us a screenshoot.

Comment: Can you not just add a white fill or rectangle behind the PDF image?

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with this in the past, and it's quite an easy solution:

You simply add a white box behind your document in the PDF editor.

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1087337

Comment: The answer could be shorter, but that is basically about it.